# Check an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of $\lim_{ (x,y) \to (3,1)} \frac{x}{y} = 3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I am going to prove
$$\lim_{ (x,y) \to (3,1)} \frac{x}{y} = 3$$
by using $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

**My Attempts**

**Preliminary Analysis**

For every $\epsilon >0$, we need to find a suitable $\delta$ such that:

If $\Vert (x,y)-(3,1)\Vert _2 < \delta$ then $\left| \frac{x}{y} - 3\right| < \epsilon.$

First note that
$$\left| \frac{x}{y} - 3\right| = \left| \frac{x}{y} - 3y + 3y -3\right| \le \left|\frac{1}{y}\right||x-3| + 3|y-1|.$$

It is obvious that
$$|x-3| \le \Vert (x,y)-(3,1)\Vert_2\; \text{and} \; |y-1| \le \Vert (x,y)-(3,1)\Vert_2.$$

Suppose $\Vert (x,y)-(3,1)\Vert_2 < \frac{1}{2}$ then $|y-1| <\frac{1}{2}.$ As a result we have
$$\frac{1}{2} < y < \frac{3}{2} \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{|y|} < 2.$$

Hence,
$$\left| \frac{x}{y} - 3\right| \le \left|\frac{1}{y}\right||x-3| + 3|y-1|< 2\delta+3\delta = 5\delta.$$

**Formal Proof**

For every $\epsilon > 0$, we must
choose
$$\delta= \min\left\{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\epsilon}{5}\right\}.$$

If $\Vert (x,y)-(3,1)\Vert _2 < \delta$ then $\left| \frac{x}{y} - 3\right| < \epsilon.$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: If I were to read the formal proof and avoid the preliminary analysis, the conclusion should be transparent but it is not. Since you only write "if A, then B$ and there is not argumentation.

Comment: @Niccolo, pay close attention: $$\left|\frac{x}{y}-3\right|=\left|\frac{x}{y}-3y+3y-3\right|\leqslant\left|\frac{1}{y}\right||x-3\color{red}{\mathbf{y^2}}|+3|y-1|.$$

Comment: Replace "we must choose" by "we choose" (other choices were possible).

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not correct because

$\left|\dfrac xy-3\right|=\left|\dfrac xy-3y+3y-3\right|\leqslant\left|\dfrac1y\right||x-3|+3|y-1|$

is wrong (see my comment).

So you could proceed as follows:

$\begin{align}\left|\dfrac xy-3\right|&=\left|\dfrac 1y\right|\,\big|x-3y\big|=\left|\dfrac 1y\right|\,\big|x-3-3\big(y-1\big)\big|\leqslant\\&\leqslant \left|\dfrac1y\right|\bigg(\big|x-3\big|+3\big|y-1\big|\bigg).\end{align}$

For any $\,\varepsilon>0\,,\,$ we choose $\,\delta=\min\left\{\dfrac12,\dfrac{\varepsilon}8\right\}>0\,.$

If $\;\big\Vert(x,y)-(3,1)\big\Vert_2<\delta\,,\;$ then

$\big|x-3\big|\leqslant\big\Vert(x,y)-(3,1)\big\Vert_2<\delta\;\;,$

$\big|y-1\big|\leqslant\big\Vert(x,y)-(3,1)\big\Vert_2<\delta\;\;,$

$\left|\dfrac1y\right|=\dfrac1{\big|1+(y\!-\!1)\big|}\leqslant\dfrac1{1-\big|y\!-\!1\big|}<\dfrac1{1\!-\!\delta}\leqslant\dfrac1{1\!-\!\frac12}=2\;.$

Consequently,

$\left|\dfrac xy-3\right|\leqslant \left|\dfrac1y\right|\bigg(\big|x-3\big|+3\big|y-1\big|\bigg)<2\big(\delta+3\delta\big)=8\delta<\varepsilon\,.$

Comment: (+1) A wider choice (but less in the OP's spirit) would be: we only need $0<\delta<1$ and $\frac{4\delta}{1-\delta}<\epsilon,$ so we may choose any (positive) $\delta<\min\left(1,\frac\epsilon{4+\epsilon}\right).$

Comment: @AnneBauval, you are absolutely right, for that reason I avoided writing “*must*” and just wrote “*choose*”.